# Sharepoint 2013 monthly task summary

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tasks, reports, sharepoint-email

I want to know if it is possible to enable monthly task summary even if there is no changes on that particular task, solution can be via powershell/workflow/sharepoint.

Idea is that my supervisor wants to have monthly summary of all incomplete tasks and tasks created in current month.

They would love to receive mail from sharepoint with summary of all those tasks, in which they could see all the info like they see in regular summary when something changes in task.

Please give me some idea or if solution if anyone has done something like this before.

They have ms exchange 2010, and they have one main site with one task list, and couple of subsites. Each of subsites has it's own task list.

Comment: Which version of sharepoint are you using? Does Custom solution work?

Comment: I'm using 2013 Server Ent. Haven't tried with any custom solution yet, do you have some to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you two ways to do that

- **Using SharePoint Timer Job which runs monthly**

You can create a custom timer job which will iterate through all the the sites and then tasks list within a webapp. Then for each tasklist you can find the newly created and unfinished tasks format them in a presentable way and then use SpUtility.SendMail() to send the mail.

- **Using PowerShell and task scheduler**

Basically you do the same task in powershell and then schedule the script to run monthly.

- Workflow options are also available but you'll need to attach those workflows with every task list and that's in my opinion is not that much scalable.

Do let me know if you want the code or want further info on workflow solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thx for the tips. I would like to try do this by myself, I have never worked with VB or PowerShell in SharePoint. Can you give me a few guidelines?

Comment: here's a quick article to write a timer job but if you are very new to object model then achieving this will take time am afraid: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S

Comment: you can do something similar to this: http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=241